# Google Web Toolkit - UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am new in GWT. I want to ask some questions about UI binder:

```
<ui:with field='res' type='com.my.app.widgets.logoname.Resources'/>
```

(1) Refer to code above. What is the meaning of type? Is meant the file location?
(2) Why need to use external resource for the UI binder?
(3) When I write css, in java file should I need to write the "extends CssResource" word?

I really don't understand. Please help me to answer the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui:with field='res' type='com.my.app.widgets.logoname.Resources'/>
```

- Refer to code above. What is the meaning of type? Is meant the file location?

  Here type is equivalent to below java code

  ```
  Resources res = new com.my.app.widgets.logoname.Resources();
  ```
- Why need to use external resource for the UI binder?

  Sometimes your template will need to work with styles or other objects that come from outside of your template.
- When I write css, in java file should I need to write the "extends CssResource" word?

  Yes you have to use `extends CssResource`

---

For detailed explaination and samples please have a look at [GWT UIBinder - Using an external resource](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_an_external_resource).

Find a sample code here about [GWT - Using UiBinder](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_uibinder.htm).

> Here is the key points of using UIBinder:

- The UiBinder is a framework designed to separate Functionality and View of User Interface.
- The UiBinder framework allows developers to build gwt applications as HTML pages with GWT widgets configured throughout them.
- The UiBinder framework makes easier collaboration with UI designers who are more comfortable with XML, HTML and CSS than Java source code
- The UIBinder provides a declarative way of defining User Interface.
- The UIBinder seperates the programmic logic from UI.
- The UIBinder is similar to what JSP is to Servlets.

Comment: @Braj: `<ui:with>` is actually equivalent to `GWT.create()` rather than `new`. It also respects the `@UiField(provided=true)` from your owner class (for cases you want to provide a specific instance, or `GWT.create()` wouldn't work). I think it also respects `@UiFactory` methods of the owner class.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Thanks a lot. Please can you tell, What `GWT.create()` does internally?

Comment: @Braj It checks rebind rules (`<generate-with>` and `<replace-with>` in your gwt.xml files); calls the generator if a `<generate-with>` is found and `new` the generated class, or `new` the replacing class if a `<replace-with>` is found, and falls back to a simple `new` of the type if no rebind rule is found. See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html